# Parsed with column specification error in R and boxplot issues

Tags: r, runtime-error

I'm new to R so apologies if this is a basic question. Check the previously asked questions on here still having an issue. I'm trying to read a csv file and perform EDA. I haven't had trouble reading files before but am now getting error message "Parsed with column specification". Furthermore, when I try to create a boxplot (which also previously worked fine, receiving error  "NAs introduced by coercion", however when I look at the file there are no missing data entries. I'm assuming these two errors are related, and trying to figure out how to resolve. Thanks for all of your help and patience with this newbie!

Comment: "Parsed with column specification" is not an error. The function is telling you what it guessed for each column type (character , double, etc). The "NA introduced by coercion" means the value did not look like a number so it pretend it as NA. Adding an example of the issues would help.

Comment: have you changed from `read.csv` to `read_csv`?

Comment: Hi, I just checked: it actually was (when I posted) read_csv, and changing it to read.csv seems to help! Thank you so much, I feel a little silly asking about what turned out to be a simple change, but I will definitely remember that for next time!

Answer (score 2):

I arrived here because `tidyr::read_csv()` returned

```
Parsed with column specification:
```

This is not an error - the message **simply lets you know any assumptions `read_csv()` made when it read in your data**. It's generally nothing to worry about.

You may want to check the classes of your columns to make sure they are what you expect them to be. You can do so with `sapply(df, class)`